# Get dimensions an autorotated UIView will be given after screen is rotated?

Tags: ios, autorotate

**The question:** Is it possible to obtain the size that an autorotated UIView will be given after the screen is rotated, but to obtain this value *before* the rotation is completed?  If so, how?

**Background:**  I'm building an iPad app that has a screen where several UILabels are arranged in columns within a containing UIView (which is smaller than the screen's main UIView.)  The number of labels and the length of text in each label is not known during compile-time.  They are layed out on the screen dynamically at runtime with an algorithm that tries to choose the optimum number of columns and widths that keeps things from being clipped off the screen.  To make the rejiggering process appear as smooth as possible to the user, I believe I need to do this inside of:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

But of course this method is called before the rotation is completed and hence the need to know in advance the size that the containing UIView will soon have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will achieve what you're looking for.

In iOS 4, you can make the moves a little less jarring by animating the moving of your controls/subviews, even though it takes place in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` (I know it doesn't sound like it, but it makes a huge difference). Thus, if you want to animate the move of a button to newFrame, it's as simple as:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{ 
    [button setFrame:newFrame]; 
}];
```

Finally, judicious use of `autoResizingMask`, helps immensely, too, though I gather that this is not a possibility given that you are moving controls around in respect to each other.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  `viewWillLayoutSubviews` did the trick.  Since this method is called during an autorotate operation after the container is assigned its new size, there's no need to obtain it through any extra tricks.  `container.frame.size` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

You can find all those methods here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm aware of that method, thanks.  I don't want to do it there, because it will mean the view rotates and *then* the labels all snap into a new place or size.  I'd like everything to be ready at the moment the rotation is complete.

Comment: On iOS 5, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is even better, doing it as part of the rotation.

Comment: In iOS 4, you can make the moves a little less jarring by animating the moving, even though it takes place in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation (I know it doesn't sound like it, but it makes a huge difference). Also, judicious use of autoResizingMask (90% of the time, that does the job), helps immensely, too.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Unfortunately autoResizeMask won't work because I'm having to draw new columns and shift some labels over in some cases, rather than just resizing what's there.  I do look forward to learning more about custom animations at some point though.

Comment: The animation is trivial: For example, to move button, having come up with the newFrame, I just do `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{ [button setFrame:newFrame]; }];`. And, I think you'll be pretty happy with viewWillLayoutSubviews, too, as it does precisely what you asked for (albeit, just for iOS 5).

Comment: Robert, I just realized your `viewWillLayouSubviews` suggestion is exactly what I needed to trigger the redraw, and it happens after my container has been assigned its new size.  That makes my original question moot.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.  Thanks!